# Generate maven archetype from project and variable replacement

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype, archetypes

I'm trying to generate an archetype from a project, but I have some issues to solve.

First of all, I've a file like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ${artifactId}
....
```

Then, I use the command:

```
mvn clean archetype:create-from-project -Darchetype.filteredExtentions=* -Darchetype.postPhase=install
```

But, when I try to generate a new project from the installed archetype, the result of this operation is this:

```
#set( $symbol_pound = '#' )
#set( $symbol_dollar = '$' )
#set( $symbol_escape = '\' )
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ${symbol_dollar}{artifactId}
  ...
```

Is there a way to obtain a file in which the property "`${artifactId}`" is replaced during the new project creation?

Thanks all

Comment: What does the file look like in the built archetype, prior to use?